# How could I use C# to send and receive data from Web Service directly?

Tags: c#, web-services

As a tester, i was asked to test a web service via C#. I've no idea how to use C# directly to send data to Web Service. Could you please give some samples about it? BTW, please do not use the proxy method.

Thanks
Sut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [SOAPUI](http://www.soapui.org/) if you are trying to test SOAP web services directly. Trying to call them using HTTP requests and then parsing the resulting SOAP is going to be quite a chore if you have to use C# and not use the imported proxies.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. But I also want to know how to handle the data transfer back by the Web Service...

Answer (score 1):

Note: You'd be much better of if you talk to whoever asked you to do something... instead of asking strangers.

In most cases call to web service is simple HTTP POST or GET. There are plenty of ways to perform it directly  - i.e. "How to: Send Data Using the WebRequest Class" ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx).

And response from web service is generally XML - again plenty of classes to read including XmlDocument and XDocument.